# Show Webview just on part of the screen(android)?

Tags: java, android, xml, webview, android-webview

I want my Webview on part of the screen:

code: xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"    
tools:context=".Browser" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/Browser"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="76dp" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

java:

```
WebView Browser;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.floap);
    Ready();
}
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public void Ready(){
Browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.Browser);
Browser.loadUrl("http://google.com");
WebSettings  settings= Browser.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);                
}
```

when i run this the webview appears in full screen and not like a part of the screen

How can I fix it?

Thank You,

Boaz

Comment: Try android:layout_height="match_parent"

Comment: Your parent relative layout has background white color and so is google page's background, so how do you differentiate the two view's. Try setting different background color to your RelativeLayout and check, I think your coding is fine.. Let me know otherwise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it:

i added

```
  Browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()       
        {
     @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
    {
        return false;
    }
});
```

The problem was that google redirected me to the browser.

I found it here:

[Url open in full screen instead of Webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726611/url-open-in-full-screen-instead-of-webview)

Answer (score 0):

Put WebView and a simple View in a linear layout and give weight = 1.0 to both.

Comment: i have changed it and then it shows the WebView in white and after one secong it opens google in fullscreen

Comment: @BoazKatzir.. obviously it will load the url that you are giving.

Comment: yes, but it loads it on fullscreen and i want it only on a part of the screen

Comment: @BoazKatzir.. i said give layout_weight="1.0" to both webview and view..in this case both will have 50% of the screen..so your webview will not be shown to full screen.

Comment: like this:<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
... >




        <View
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/Browser"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="76dp" />   
</LinearLayout>

but also then it shows me google on fullscreen

Comment: @BoazKatzir.. put width=0dp to both webViwe and View...and weight=1.0

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32232/discussion-between-boaz-katzir-and-noman)